# Mount view component only on a single Rails View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I create a view component to handle some selects...
I need to load this component on a single Rails View.

I init my component with:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Product from '../components/product.vue'
import axios from 'axios';

Vue.prototype.$http = axios

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('app'))
  console.log('caricato Vue');
  const app = new Vue({
    render: h => h(Product)
  }).$mount('#product_search')
})
```

And in my Rails page I have the `#product_search` div

Rails try to load the component on every page and give me the error:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js:619 [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #product_search
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Because Vue tries to render the component (on `#product_search`) when `document` is ready, meaning on every page of your application.

You can add a condition to prevent the null error:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let element = document.querySelector('#product_search')
  if (element) {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('app'))
    console.log('caricato Vue');
    const app = new Vue({
      render: h => h(Product)
    }).$mount('#product_search')
  }
})
```